# Get depth stored in different FBOs that has different shaders

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, opengl-3, depth-buffer

The goal of my program is to compare between the depth of the RGB-D camera and OpenGL depth.

The camera is facing a model (real one) and it has its own shaders (fragment and vertex).

To make comparison, a 3D Model is made, this one has also its own shaders (the depth is normally linearized as I followed what is explained in this tutorial: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing).

So the comparison will be done on the depth received from the camera and the depth related to the 3D model.

So,the steps I have done are:

1.In the initialization function

1. Create two textures for each one (color and depth textures).
2. Generate two FBOs (one for the camera, the other one for the 3D Model).
3. Attach textures to their FBOs.

```
  /* Other stuff needed for initialization */

  ...

  // Generate color texture
  glGenTextures(1, &colorTex);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTex);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, _windowWidth, _windowHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  // Generate depth texture
  glGenTextures(1, &depthTex);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTex);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, _windowWidth, _windowHeight, 0,  GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


  // Attach the color and depth textures to current FrameBuffer
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &_fboGL);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fboGL);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTex, 0);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTex, 0);
```

In the main function for Drawing and rendering

1. Render the camera stream by binding its FBO.
2. Draw 3D Model by binding its own FBO.
3. Try to print openGL depth related to the 3D Model.

A fragment of the code looks like below:

```
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, camColorTex, 0);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, camDepthTex, 0);


  glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glClearColor(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 1.f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  /*******************************************/
  /* Some code for displaying camera stream  */
  /*******************************************/

  .............


  drawModelFunction();
  printDepthFunction();

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, camColorTex, 0);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, camDepthTex, 0);

  /***********************************************************/
  /* Some stuff to render a GUI to interact with the program */
  /***********************************************************/

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
  glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, _windowWidth, _windowHeight, 0, 0, _windowWidth, _windowHeight, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
  glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, _windowWidth, _windowHeight, 0, 0, _windowWidth, _windowHeight, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

A fragment code for **drawModelFunction()**

```
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboGL); 
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTex, 0);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTex, 0);


  /*************************************/
  /* Some stuff to render the 3D Model */
  /*************************************/
```

A fragment code for **printDepthFunction()**

```
  GLfloat *pixels = (GLfloat *)malloc(_windowWidth * _windowHeight * sizeof *pixels);

  assert(pixels);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTex);
  glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, pixels);

  /* print the the values stored in **pixels** */

  free(pixels);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

When I try to display the values stored in the depth, I only obtain one value "1.0f" and the color returns me only the value "0.0f". In addition to that, the rendering is not here as I mixed everything with FBOs. I have a screen with mixture of camera stream, a red square inserted in the middle of the screen with the GUI in it (that took the red color of the square). And No 3D Model. (This is the result I have obtained after binding the framebuffers everywhere like shown before).

Comment: Anyone please could help me. I'm really struggling with this for days now. 

Now I have different values but I have around 80% of NaN values. Is this normal ?

Comment: You should always check glCheckFramebufferStatus() once so that you know it was initialized ok. If possible you should try enable KHR_debug/ARB_debug_output extension with GL debug context to see if any gl errors are being logged.

Comment: @JATothrim Apparently there's no problem in the initialization (checked with `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) ` as you suggested me. 
I haven't really found how to enable KHR_debug/ARB_debug_output extension  but used these lines of code for debugging (don't know if it is suitable)
`glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
  glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
  glDebugMessageCallback(debugMessage, NULL);
  glDebugMessageControl(GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM, GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM, GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM, 0, NULL, GL_TRUE);
`

Comment: Obtained this:
`Message: GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION error generated. Operation is not valid because a bound framebuffer is not framebuffer complete.
Source: API
Type: Error
ID: 1286
Severity: High `

Comment: Actually, I have different values and among them many of large values (inf, like : `-2658455991569831745807614120560689152.000000`) and some NaN values (< 1%)

Comment: I suspect the `GetTexImage()` operation to CPU buffer is at fault. By default GL sets row alignment to 4 which confuses many people. Test with `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` before getTexImage().